# Using Pest.rs, how can I add a capture to the tree?

Tags: rust, peg, pest

Let's say I have a rule like this,

```
conf = { SOI ~ ("FOO" ~ "BAR"?) ~ NEWLINE ~ EOI }
```

This will produce a tree that does not distinguish between "FOO" and "FOOBAR" this,

```
Pair {
    rule: conf,
    span: Span {
        str: "FOOBAR\n",
        start: 0,
        end: 7,
    },
    inner: [
        Pair {
            rule: EOI,
            span: Span {
                str: "",
                start: 7,
                end: 7,
            },
            inner: [],
        },
    ],
}
```

However, this isn't what I want, what I want is a tree like this,

```
Pair {
    rule: conf,
    span: Span {
        str: "FOOBAR\n",
        start: 0,
        end: 7,
    },
    inner: [
        Pair {
            rule: term,
            span: Span {
                str: "FOOBAR",
                start: 0,
                end: 6,
            },
            inner: [],
        },
        Pair {
            rule: EOI,
            span: Span {
                str: "",
                start: 7,
                end: 7,
            },
            inner: [],
        },
    ],
}
```

Which I could produce with this,

```
term = { "FOO" ~ "BAR"? }
conf = { SOI ~ term ~ NEWLINE ~ EOI }
```

But I don't want to actually have to specify a `term` for this, I want to be able to inline the specification. I want to do this because essentially I am trying to model these conditionals, [`ifdef`, `ifndef`, `elifdef`, `elifndef`, `else`, and `endif`](https://github.com/Exim/exim/blob/e2be2df5c0760e2b6a7870c88ad486a23f5e4b01/src/src/readconf.c#L546). And It would like cleaner to say,

```
conditional = {
  ( "ifndef" | "ifdef" ) ~ conditional_block
  ( ( "elifndef" | "elifdef" ) ~ conditional_block )?
  ( "else" ~ conditional_block )?
}
```

Then to have model each `ifdef`, `ifndef`; and `elifdef`, `elifndef` as two separate tokens that will only be used there.

```
_if      = { ".ifndef" | ".ifdef" }
_elseif  = { ".elifndef" | ".elifdef" }
_else    = { ".else" }
_endif   = { ".endif" }
conditional = {
  _if ~ conditional_block
  ~ ( _elseif ~ conditional_block )?
  ~ ( _else ~ conditional_block )?
  ~ _endif
}
```

Comment: Where would the name `term` come from?